# Android Studio on Ubuntu 14

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I am unable to install android studio on ubuntu 14.

The archive provided here https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other does not have the entire setup. The readme file says -

> The Android SDK archive initially contains only the basic SDK tools. It does
>   not contain an Android platform or any third-party libraries. In fact, it
>   doesn't even have all the tools you need to develop an application.

Tried with the procedure described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html), but the ppa is not available https://launchpad.net/~paolorotolo/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/sdk/index.html).
The [link](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/sdk/index.html#Other) you posted points to the Android SDK which is required for Android programming - when you install the Android Studio it'll ask you to provide the Android SDK too.